# Volume button listener on IOS(React Native) doesn't work. I need it for Camera to take a photo

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, camera

I am trying to detect when the user presses volume up button within a react-native application. I need to take a photo by `react-native-camera` on volume button click.
I've tried to connect native `VolumeTriggerModule.h` to subscribe for volume button from React Native code, but it's a problem for me. Can't do that.

How do I have listen to physical buttons with react native?
Is there any nice package for this.

I found that there is something similar in `react-native-vision-camera`, but not sure if I can replace `react-native-camera`.

Comment: `import { NativeModules, DeviceEventEmitter, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';`


`const { VolumeTriggerModule } = NativeModules;`
`const nativeEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(VolumeTriggerModule);`

`nativeEventEmitter.addListener('VolumeTrigger', onVolumeChange);`


This helped and native module VolumeTriggerModule